# Including server Java script files into server.js in Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

I have Server.js file where we can write server connection and Post and get methods.
I am facing the issue that i want to include other js files in server.js

here alluser.js file

```
var app = express();

module.exports={

app.get('/allusers',function(req,res){

  usersmodel.find({'approvalstatus':'true'},function(err,users){
   if(err) return next(err);
   res.send(users);
   console.log('getting');
  });

});

};
```

Server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs=require('fs');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
//var mongojs = require('mongojs');
app.use(bodyparser.json());
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

require('./allusers.js);// Here i am getting error
```

I have tried to get those alluser.js content replaced into require(./alluser.js).Even i have tried to get this using FileSystem of node.js

Can you please help me out of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are not using an Express Router for this?

Maybe change your alluser.js file to something like this.

```
var app = require('express').Router();

module.exports={
  app.get('/',function(req,res){
    usersmodel.find({'approvalstatus':'true'},function(err,users){
    if(err) return next(err);
      res.send(users);
      console.log('getting');
    });
  });
};
```

and your server.js to.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs=require('fs');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
//var mongojs = require('mongojs');
app.use(bodyparser.json());
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

app.use('/allusers', require('./alluser.js'));
```